# Slideshow Viewing app in Android

Tags: android, slideshow, android-image

I have just now started with android. I am done with Simple Hello World projects and JSON based small projects.

I am planning to create a app to view slideshow of images.
Example : Folder will contain 4 to 5 images.

My app shld read the folder and display the images inside it as slideshow.

It would be of great help if anyone could guide or advice me, what all are the concepts to start with to proceed with this app.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend checking out this guide from the google developer website.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Instead of a textview use an imageview on the fragment.